# Two different applications with the login page in one of them

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've made 2 distinct solutions, but one of them has a login page. I want that when you log in the application, my client will be able to access the second application also. If my client haven't logged in the application and try to access any application, he will be redirected to the Login page that exists only in one solution.

```
   Solution 1
        - Login page
        - Ui

   solution 2
        - Ui
```

To do a validation in my Solution 1 is simple because my Login page exists there, but I don't know how can I see in my Solution 2 if the client is already logged in.

Can you give me some tips ?

I [read this article and tried to implement the code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429166/Basics-of-Single-Sign-on-SSO) but in my case, exists 2 different applications (solutions)

Both of them will run under the same domain

Comment: Are these Windows applications, web, ... ?

Comment: @Habo Web Applications, both using MVC 4

Comment: Will they both be hosted on the same domain?

Comment: @RichardDalton Yes, But we have 2 solutions, and we want just one login to access all applications, and if the user is already logged in, then the another application has to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they are both hosted on the same domain they can both share the same forms authentication cookie.

All you would need to do is ensure the forms authentication settings are the same in both of the web.config files. This way when an unauthorised user tries to access Solution 2, it will redirect them to Solution 1 (As that will be the `loginUrl` attribute in the web.config)  to login.

Comment: Without any SSO solutions ? For example, in default MVC 4 template we have the following tag in web.config `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /></authentication>` I need just put this in the other solution and deploy both in the same domain ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos Yes, except that in the other solution you will want the absolute path to the Login url for the first solution (Something like `/SolutionOne/Account/Login`)

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid that the project changes, like, "now we want cross-domain", so, I'm trying to look for a solution that can be fit both cases, i.e. cross-domain and one-domain

Comment: For cross domain you will definitely want to look into an SSO solution.